# How to use fetchColumn() in FETCH_ASSOC?

Tags: php, pdo

How to use fetchColumn() in FETCH_ASSOC? I want the output show each month such as (July, June, May, April, March), but my codes below output show alternative month such as (July, May, March), may I know how to fix it?

```
$poslaju = "%poslaju%";

$sql = "SELECT count(*), payment_date, sum(postage) FROM sale WHERE seller_id=? && courier LIKE ? GROUP BY YEAR(payment_date), MONTH(payment_date) ORDER BY payment_date DESC Limit 36"; 
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($user_id, $poslaju));
if(!$result){
    //show error messages
}

while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $payment_date_db = $r['payment_date'];
    $payment_date_db2 = date("d-F-Y", strtotime($payment_date_db));
    $postage_db = $r['sum(postage)'];
    $Count = $q->fetchColumn();     
    echo $payment_date_db2 . " - " . $money_currency . $postage_db . " - " . $Count . " parcels <br />";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? (NB: I've removed the **WHERE** clause.)

[SQL Fiddle <-- click me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27016/14)

It's predominately your SQL statement that needed a bit of work. Only selecting **payment_date** and not **YEAR(payment_date), MONTH(payment_date)** meant that you would just get the latest date from the grouped dates.

If you post the output you're trying to create it may help with any further answers.

I'm not 100% sure without testing it, but I think your:

```
$Count = $q->fetchColumn();
```

is taking a column from the **next** result and may not behave as you expect. Per the manual:

> PDOStatement::fetchColumn — Returns a single column from the next row
>   of a result set

If you use the **AS** keyword (as I've demonstrated in the SQL Fiddle example), you can just use:

```
echo $r['count_items'];
```

Comment: pefect! It is what I am looking for. count(*) AS `count_items`. It works like charm, thank u very much.